# Google chrome is showing blank response on ajax request

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a login page which works as a login page should work. It takes username and password, does an ajax request and gets back a response if the entry matches on the database. It was working fine for over a year now but today its the request is not returning anything. The response is blank. And it only happening on Chrome 73.0.3683.86. Other browsers are working normally.

Its a post request so i tried changing it to get. The issue still exists.

You can view the page here. https://www.easypermit.net/#/login/signin

**Edit 1**

[This it the console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XNlF.png)

[Header from network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLs95.png)

[And the response. They are blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGUMB.png)

Comment: what does the network tab say? Console.log?

Comment: Chrome 73 changes to cross-origin requests in chrome extension content scripts are described at https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches

Comment: @Andy I have updated the post and added screenshots from console and network tab. Please check them

Comment: We're having the exact same problem, did you ever figure out a resolution? In our case it's not a cross origin request.

Comment: The issue was resolved automatically. It must have been related to a bug on Google Chrome itself.

Comment: I've been noticing this issue for the past couple of weeks on certain requests.